# What is issssi, sssdi in mysqli?

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

```
$con = new mysqli("localhost","root","","my_db");
$stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO mytbl(name,dob,gen,dt) VALUES ('$name','$datepicker','$gen',now())");
$stmt->bind_param('issssi', $name, $datepicker, $gen);
$stmt->execute();
$newId = $stmt->id;
$stmt->close();
```

I've started doing this type of codes recently so I didn't really get these stuff "issssi" "sssdi". What are the uses of these things? Does it vary from statement to statement and how to bind that `now()` in  `$stmt->bind_param`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reading the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) might be a good start.

The characters define the types of the parameters. In this case you're giving more types than parameters, so it's wrong.

What's most wrong is that you're not using any parameters at all. You're still just putting the values of the variables as is into the SQL string and are vulnerable for injections and other problems.

There is no need to do anything to the `now()` if you want the current timestamp. The server will handle it. If you want some other timestamp then you can make it into a bindable variable like the others.

Comment: totally got it.. it should be like `$stmt->bind_param('sssi', $name, $datepicker, $gen);` .. and how can i bind that `now()` ??

Comment: @StillLearning And remove the variables from the prepare statement and replace them with placeholders. You have no reason to replace the `now()` with a parameter if it does what you want and you don't specifically want some other timestamp there.

Comment: `$stmt->bind_param('sss', $_POST['name'],.,.);`  like this .. and what are the other timestamp which i can make into bind variable.. ?? bcz for that `now()` i m getting a warning : mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of elements in type definition string doesn't match number of bind variables

Comment: @StillLearning Yes, because you have no parameters in the prepare statement. You need to remove the `$name` etc and replace them with `?`. Check the documentation.

Comment: thank u thank u so much .. my code works perfectly with no warning .. :)